# Any help Publishing a Private Google AddOn

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, publish, google-docs

But why is google like this...
I am trying to publish a private google doc addon, every time I try publish > Deploy as add-on it tells me to visit the **g suite marketplace sdk** however I have already and the status there is **Approved**!.

The app url then returns the following error.
**The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know**

Any help/recommendation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nowadays deploy as add-on will always tell you to visit the G Suite Marketplace SDK. What do you mean by "the app url"? Is this the link to the add-on listing?

Comment: That was the link appended to the "Approved" message I got after publishing on the G Suite Marketplace SDK, I assume this would redirect to a store.

Comment: It's not a redirect, it points directly to the G Suite Marketplace listing for your add-on. Maybe a glitch on Google's side. I suggest you to search the issue tracker and add more details like when you published the add-on, if you are the G Suite admin, if this domain already has other add-ons published or this is the first one.

Comment: Okay... so on this particular project this is the only published addon. also is there any need to create anything or register on the chrome web store?

Comment: It's good to know but that was not what I asked, in anycase [edit] the question to include on it all the relevant details. By the way, nowadays add-ons can't be published to the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Is the add-on published as *unlisted*? @afrologicinsect

Comment: Yes, it was set as Private and unlisted.

Comment: Are you sure that the add-on is indeed associated to the GCP project from where you get the link from? Moreover, are you still getting the error? @afrologicinsect

Comment: Yes I still get an error when I visit the site, but I'll manage, thanks ale13, Ruben.

Answer (score 0):

*This might be an issue*, so I suggest you file it on Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191597&template=823910) **OR** if you have G Suite account, you can contact Google Support by choosing one of the options available [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en).

#### Reference

- [G Suite Marketplace How To Get Help](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/support);
- [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en).